# give feedback on this pointer program

Tags: c++, pointers

This is relatively simple program. But I want to get some feedback about how I can improve this program (if any), for example, unnecessary statements?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

double Average(double*,int);

int main()
{

    ifstream inFile("data2.txt");

    const int SIZE = 4;
    double *array = new double(SIZE);
    double *temp;
    temp = array;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        inFile >> *array++;
    }
    cout << "Average is: " << Average(temp, SIZE) << endl;
}

double Average(double *pointer, int x)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        sum += *pointer++;
    }
    return (sum/x);
}
```

The codes are valid and the program is working fine. But I just want to hear what you guys think, since most of you have more experience than I do (well I am only a freshman ... lol)

Thanks.

Comment: I would make this program longer. Pass in the file name on the command line. Check if the file exists. If not, error out in a good way, return -1 or 1. Also, prefer plain old arrays to pointers. Extra pointers make a good learning exercise, but worse production code (unless there are specific constraints).

Comment: yes. initially this program was written in array. but i wrote this because we just finished pointers. so i took a couple minutes modify the first half of the old program. great idea, Hamish!

Answer (score 4):

Fix the memory leak.
i.e delete temp;
Also, check if the file is open/created..etc

ideally, you should manipulate/traverse the array using your temp variable instead of using *array itself

Comment: Also, deal with empty files, partially filled files. What if the file has more than 4 entries? Put a space between `double*,` and `int` in `double Average(double*,int);`.

Comment: i didn't get the third statement "traverse the array..." may you describe it a little bit more in detail, please? thank you!

Comment: @johnWong - "traverse the array..." is what you are doing now. accessing one element at a time in the for loop until the last one

Comment: hi, sysadmin. thanks. please be patient with me, if you think I am being stupid :D. haha. i see. i thought i needed to save the first address, so i saved it in temp. how should i rewrite that part? *array itself is just a pointer variable, right?

Comment: @JohnWong - nobody thinks you are stupid. :). basically, what you have done is correct. but my suggestion is to not move the pointer to which memory was allocated. do the other way round. i.e in the for loop instead of using *array use *temp and pass the *array into Average()

Comment: i got you. is there a speed or security difference b/w passing the original allocation *array vs *temp? thanks sysadmin. lol hahaa cuz i keep asking questions may be obvious to some people :) thanks dude

Comment: no issue in this simple program. but in a big project, if something goes wrong because of this, you would spend a lot of time unnecessarily debugging...thats all.

Answer (score 4):

You are not initializing your array correctly.  This statement:

```
double *array = new double(SIZE);
```

Allocates one double and initializes it to the value of SIZE.  What you should be doing is using array allocation:

```
double *array = new double[SIZE];
```

Another general problem is you rarely ever want to assign dynamically allocated memory to a raw pointer.  If you want to use base types instead of higher level objects such as `std::vector`, you should always use a smart pointer:

```
boost::scoped_array<double> array(new double[SIZE]);
```

Now the array will automatically get freed regardless of how you leave your scope (i.e. from a newly added return or from an exception).

Comment: hi, thanks. thank you for pointing out the two differences. new double [SIZE] is an array allocation, right. and i do treat memory allocation as linear arrangement, which is an array, i suppose. i am still not quite understand the problem with (). I do see your point about [] for an array allocation.

Comment: @JohnWong - `new double(SIZE)` allocates **1** double object.  By itself, there is nothing wrong with that; the issue is that the code treats it like an array which causes a "buffer overflow".

Answer (score 2):

Since we're talking about C++, I would suggest using STL containers and algorithms. I also find that in most cases it's better to use references or smart pointers (e.g. boost::shared_ptr) instead of raw pointers. In this case there's no need for pointers at all.

Here is how you could write your program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("doubles.txt");
    istream_iterator<double> start(f), end;
    vector<double> v(start, end);

    if (v.empty())
    {
        cout << "no data" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    double res = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
    cout << "Average: " << res / v.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wooo this is very advance. We did touch on STL and vectors, but not too much. Thanks for spending ur time, it's a great reference.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is 0, then Average will generate a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: How about when x is negative? Do you want to deal with exceptions or use C-style errno, other? So far there is no C++ really. I bet this program will compile with a C compiler.

Comment: @Hamish: I bet it doesn't with it using `new` and iostreams.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some "code review" comments:

In main():

1. Change SIZE to "`size_`t" instead of `int`
2. Why SIZE is uppercase? (May be the author's convention is to have constants as uppercase, in that case it is fine.)
3. Combine temp declaration and assignment into one statement as: `double * temp = array;`
4. What if `inFile` is not available or can't be opened for reading?
5. What if `inFile` have less than SIZE number of items?
6. Change the loop variable `i` to `size_t`.
7. Remove blank line before declaration of `inFile`.
8. Return some number (e.g. `0`) from `main()`.
9. Correct the allocation of array.

In Average():

1. Change the second argument of Average to `size_t`.
2. Assert and/or guard for pointer being non-NULL
3. Assert and/or guard against division by zero.

**Acknowledgement**: Some points are collected from other answers. I tried to make a complete list as far as I could.

Comment: thank you for your inputs. i really enjoy this kind of conversation. this discussion reflects how much i still need to learn :) so for size_t, do i need specify how many?